# How to configure SCSI hard drives and RAID for Poweredge 2850 web server using Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, dell-poweredge

I have a poweredge 2850 with 6 drives and a RAID controller.  I want to set up 3 pairs of RAID1 arrays to use a 1-webserver, 2 fileserver and 3backup.

Is this even possible and how do I configure it?

I see 3 drives when I check the files systems in Ubuntu but I don't know where to go from here.  I had to add the gnome GUI to check things out because the command line was too difficult.  Once I am configured I will disable the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set up 3 pairs of RAID1 arrays to use as
>   1-webserver, 2 fileserver and 3backup.
>
> Is this even possible and how do I configure it?

This is possible, and if you want to keep things really separated (e.g. no files uploaded to the array with webserver data) it will work. But:

- RAID is not backup. Repeat this mantra a few times.
   If lightning strikes, a PSU dies and takes out the system, if a thief lugs the server home, if .... then you loose primary data and backup. Good advice is not to store the backup on the manin system as primary data.
- Three arrays are really not needed. One if enough. Just put the contents in different folders and assign quota's if needed.
- Three mirrors is rather wasteful. I would consider RAID10 (with 4 drives).

> I see 3 drives when I check the files systems in Ubuntu

That seems normal. You have three arrays (each considting of two drives, which the RAID controller hides from you).

> I had to add the gnome GUI to check things out because the command line
>   was too difficult. Once I am configured I will disable the GUI.

Meh. For a home system and testing a GUI is not all that bad. It is more software, more to keep up to date, more which can fail. And if you rolled out a 100 servers then I would suggest to learn the CLI. But for a single learning home system. Use the GUI and learn how things work.

Answer (score -1):

Installing GUI on a server is an epic fail. It's like having compile tools on it.

In my opinion raid1 is like shooting yourself in groins with 6 drives. I'd simply go with Raid6. (Anything just no Raid1).

For the question:
You need to grab an install disc like [minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)/netinst.
When it boots and blinks, type: expert
After that, you get a REALLY expert setup, expert options. Set up your raid through the install. That's all.

(Yes, there is no easy way around. At least I don't know any. Maybe Windows provides some easier way.. but you have to pay the price for that.)

Comment: If you would explain why did you "-1", I'd thank you.